# Redirect api endpoint to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

is there a way to proxy to specific binary file, I mean redirect pdf file to another pdf file. 
Like`app.use('/proxy', proxy('/desiredPath'))`.

This approach works but not for the specific pdf file.

Let's say `'/files/myOldFile.pdf'` to `'/files/myUpdatedOldFile.pdf'`. Basically, I would visit endpoint `'/files/myOldFile.pdf'` but `myUpdatedOldFile.pdf` will be shown.

Someone told me that there is a way to proxypass or something like this, but I couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: Make it dynamic path then it's easy. Right now you probably serve it as static resource.

Comment: Why don't you `res.redirect` your request ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect), like:

```
app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
 res.redirect('/admin');
})
```

Comment: It would work if I would have access to API, but I need to use Proxy.